# remove archive from url :: marketpress

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

http://valeriegeffner.com/valstore/products is the site i'm working on // if you hover over the product the url is /archives/valstore/products/%the_product_name% // the problem i'm having is that the archives is being put in there for some reason && if you go to the product all links (( including nav bar )) have archives inject'd into them.

any ideas ? only solution i can think of is doing some sort of url rewriting w/ .htaccess (( tho i'm not entirely sure how to pull that off ))

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the rewrite parameter `with_front` to false inside your post type registration.

```
'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => your-posttype-slug, 'with_front' => false ),
```

See the rewrite parameter on the [register_post_type codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).